# how to use QProcess to wrap telenet.exe on Windows?

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, pyside, qprocess

I'm trying to code a wrapper class using QProcess to drive the CLI applications (e.g. telnet.exe, ftp.exe) on Windows but so far with no luck. Do you know if this is even possible?

Below is the code I used to try with telnet.exe on Windows 7. I was expecting this code will print out the "welcome message" after telnet connected to the server but there is nothing print out (from standard output or error output).

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>
#include <iostream>

class ProcessWrapper :public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ProcessWrapper();
    ~ProcessWrapper();
    void start();

public  slots:
    void readStandardError();
    void readStandardOutput();

private:
    QProcess *process;
};

ProcessWrapper::ProcessWrapper()
{
    process = new QProcess(this);
    connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(readStandardError()));
    connect(process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(readStandardOutput()));
}

void ProcessWrapper::start()
{
    if(process) {
        process->start("telnet.exe",QStringList() << "135.251.142.36");
        process->waitForStarted();
    }
}

ProcessWrapper::~ProcessWrapper()
{
    if(process) delete process;
}

void ProcessWrapper::readStandardOutput()
{
    if(process) {
        QByteArray s = process->readAllStandardOutput();
        QString str(s);
        std::cout << str.toStdString();
    }
}

void ProcessWrapper::readStandardError()
{
    if(process) {
        QByteArray s = process->readAllStandardError();
        QString str(s);
        std::cout << str.toStdString();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    ProcessWrapper p;
    p.start();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: What is exactly not working? Connect to the error() and finished() signals to get notified when the process exits.

Comment: I was expecting this code will print out the "welcome message" after telnet connected to the server but there is nothing print out (from standard output or error output).

Answer (score 0):

The function main() exit immediately after you called ProcessWrapper::start().

Comment: thanks, I added process->waitForStarted() but still can't see anything out from stand output/error.